# How to get the list of people checked into a given venue using the facebook api

Tags: android, facebook, geolocation

Is it possible to get a list of people checked into a given venue using facebook?(Similar to how i would do it with the Foursquare "herenow" api call.)

Answer (score 0):

This Graph API call gets (friends') checkins at Facebook HQ:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/166793820034304/checkins?fields=from
```

Use the Graph Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to try it out.

(And of course use the search API to get the ID of the place if you don't know it yet)

Comment: Thanks James.....Is it possible that I get a list of everyone checked in at a venue and not just friends/friends of friends?